# Using Linux or any other language to read stdout and stdout from python scripts.

Tags: python, linux, stdout, stderr

I am building client side logging library and want to capture all sys.stdout and sys.stderr messages from python scripts within a directory.
Some are "long running process" while others require manual execution.  Ideally, my script would monitor a directory capture script outputs
regardless of it's location in the directory.

Things I've tried:

-Wrapped one of the scripts and instrumented sys.stdout.  This produced the requirement to capture sys.stdouts but means I will have to wrap all the scripts in subdirectories.

-Then I looked at supervisor.  It looked promising for "long running processes" but there is a script in my directory that requires manual execution.

-Then I looked at the Linux strace.  Again, great for "long running processes" but requires knowledge of the PID.

At this point I'm open to suggestions in any language or hackery.

Comment: How about just redirecting it all to a logfile? `your-program 1> stdout.log 2> stderr.log` or `your-program &> stderr-and-stdout.log`

Comment: @NilsWerner that's an option.  Then maybe use watchdog or another monitoring module to watch for file changes and parse as needed.